# Guide to Dual-Boot Windows 11/ Ubuntu with shared storage

Tags: dual-boot, 22.04, shared-folders, 22.10

I am not sure whether this is a duplicate. At least I didn't find an answer to my problem.

**Following Situation**:
For several reasons, I want to dual-boot my laptop with Windows 11 and Ubuntu.
I need to set up Windows 11 again, so we can work with a fresh version of Windows 11.

**My Laptop**: Lenovo ThinkBook 14s Yoga TLS
Windows 11, 500GB SSD, 16GB RAM, Intel Core i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz

**Questions**:

1. Does it even make sense to Dual-Boot my Laptop with the given Specs?
2. To make a shared storage, I guess, I need to split my SSD into 3 partitions. One for Win11, one for Ubuntu, and one which both can access (formatted to NTFS?). 
   Does that make sense with a 500GB SSD?
   If so, how big do the Win11 and Ubuntu Partitions have to be?
   Is there a better solution to share files between both OS? (I want to access all files in *documents* on both OS)
3. Which Ubuntu version should I use? 22.10 or 22.04. LTS??
4. Is there a good guideline for beginners to achieve both, i.e. Dual-Boot and shared storage or can anyone guide me through it?

Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: #1 It's up to you. #2 Yes, it's the recommended way. "How big" is to each user to decide, you're asking for opinions and that's off-topic here. Of course, you should give the recommended minimum size for each, at least. #3 Again, opinion and it's up to you. 22.04 is LTS (5 years of support); 22.10 isn't. #4 Sure, you could've search right here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it even make sense to Dual-Boot my Laptop with given Specs?

The specs are good.

> To make a shared storage, I guess, I need to split my SSD in 3 partitions. One for Win11, one for Ubuntu and one which both can access (formatted to NTFS?).

You will need those partitions :

1. efi partition
2. two windows partition, one for c and one for recovery (windows creates it automatically)
3. one partition for Linux for /. The swap partition is not necessary, you can use a swap file.
4. one NTFS partition to be accessible on both systems

   - My advice :

     ```
     efi (500 mb)

     windows (250 gb)

     linux (100gb)

     shared (150 gb)
     ```

> Which Ubuntu version should I use? 22.10 or 22.04. LTS??

Use the 22.04 lts.

> Is there a good guideline for beginners to achieve both, i.e. Dual-Boot and shared storage or can anyone guide me through it?

Giude for dual boot : https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-linux-dual-booting-tutorial/

guide for a shared partition : https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/how-to-create-a-shared-storage-drive-for-dual-boot-systems/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try it out and if I have no follow-up questions, I will accept the answer :)

Comment: Feel free to ask anything you need.

Comment: I have two follow-up questions: 1. I have an eGPU Razer Core X, which will almost exclusively be used with windows. Will that produce some issues? 2. Why did you recommend 250GB for the windows partition? As far as I know Windows itself should only need 35GB or so.

Comment: Windows has a lot of updates, I have a dual boot and I always end up with a 150 gb installation with all the programs installed. You can make your size, It was only an advice :)
Fot the egpu you should not have problems, look at his https://y.tsutsumi.io/2020/08/15/egpu-linux-core-x-chroma/

Comment: Makes sense with the partition size. And I would then go an install all programs on each OS partition and use the third one exclusively for files. I guess 200GB should then suffice, cause right know with everything installed and all files I am using 200GB of my SSD.

Comment: yeah, 200 should be ok :)

Comment: After a few mistakes, I made it work!! Thank you :)

Comment: Using between 22.10 and 22.04 LTS is optional. if you want a more stable release, use 22.04. If you want a more fresh look and more features, use 22.10

Comment: Happy to hear that!